# Should I learn more about Ubuntu or Redhat , depending upon market needs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redhat

I have installed Ubuntu on local server.
There is centOS on my VPS.

Now there is different method of doing/installing things on both of them.
Someone told me to install Ubuntu as it is easy and more popular now a days.
But what i am seeing is that there is still Red Hat in most companies.

So for that i have to search the same thing twice once for doing in Ubuntu and other for RedHat.

What should i do , Should i install RedHat on local computer or should i continue with ubuntu

I want to know how the market and company trend is going towards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the only two Linuxes that are taken seriously by the corporate world are Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) and SuSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES).  Everyone else is an also-ran for serious production work. You might find others on the desktop, but not on the money-makers.

That said, there are many non-Linux UNIX platforms that are also very valuable to know:  the BSD family, Solaris, HP-UX, etc.

Comment: Where once that was true (RHEL/SLES) Ubuntu is gaining some serious traction as an upfront free distro that you can then go get support for, as opposed to a commercial distro from the get go (and consequently needing financing for all machines). The times they are a changing etc

Answer (score 2):

RedHat & Ubuntu are similar, but there are enough differences in the configuration and admin tools that it's worthwhile to learn both.  I think you'll quickly start to get a feel for what the major differences are, particularly in package management and configuring services, and the longer you use both the less you'll be searching for distribution-specific how-tos.

Answer (score 1):

These two are just different flavors of the same kernel: they have differences, but the "idea" is the same and you'll feel it in the nearest future: when you know one Linux - any other distro won't be a problem.

What I really advice you to get in common with is [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/): it's also often used in servers, and this is not Linux. It still has much in common, but has more differences from any Linux distro. Often it's rather hard to work with FreeBSD even if you know ho to do the same thing in Linux :)

Comment: good tip about expanding knowledge with FreeBSD

Comment: Sorry for ignorance but what is freeBSD. How is it differnet from ubuntu or red hat. Is it same as ubuntu. I am all confused with how manu linux are there

Comment: It's just different :) All Linux distros use the same kernel made by Linus Torvalds & Co. FreeBSD has its own kernel, and everything is made in a completely different way. However, both BSD & Linux maintain POSIX standards which also cover general command-line utilities (like `ls`) so your Linux knowledge is useful there to some extent :)

Comment: It's worth double-underlining what o_O Tync said - that _FreeBSD is NOT Linux_

Comment: Linux is for people who hate Microsoft, and BSD is for people who love Unix. Or so they say.

Answer (score 1):

Redhat or Ubuntu will never for force you to learn the system below the GUI's.
If you want to learn how linux works instead of working with linux, 
I sugest you try installing a Gentoo or even a LFS (http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)
install.
This will force you to compile and bootstrap the compilers and the kernel.

You will learn much more from a failed LFS install then a 100 redhat installs.

Comment: The guy wants to know what to learn to be marketable.  I Agree that using the GUI tools isn't usually the best way of doing things and one should learn how to work things from the command line.  It's easy to just not use the GUI tools.

Comment: I can't speak for Ubuntu, but a GUI certainly isn't necessary to work with Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would put my bets on Ubuntu. I've been using it since Breezy Badger and I like the direction it's going. It's true RHEL and SLES have a strong market share in corporate "enterprise" environments but you should consider ease of use, open source package variety, how-tos, user involvement in online forums, online docs, etc.
Based on these criteria, I'd go with Ubunutu.

Comment: I forgot to add Google uses Ubuntu -- so it's kind of enterprise-y.

Answer (score 0):

I generally agree with pboin. My unscientific suggestion would be to focus on the distros in this order:

1. Red Hat (CentOS)
2. SLES (openSUSE)
3. Ubuntu LTS

Cheers